# Uninstalling Lightning causes an error

Tags: 8, drush

I am trying to uninstall Lightning. When I run `drush pm:uninstall lightning`, it throws this error.

> In PmCommands.php line 196:
>
> lightning: The Lightning module is required

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Lightning](https://www.drupal.org/project/lightning) is a distribution, not a module. Distributions and installation profiles cannot be uninstalled, once used to create a site. That's why the Lightning distribution hooks into the `drush pm:uninstall` command to make it possible.

If you aren't getting any *Welcome to the $profile name uninstaller!* message, it means the installed Lightning distribution needs to be first updated, as [Uninstalling Lightning](https://github.com/acquia/lightning/wiki/Uninstalling-Lightning) suggests.

> - If you're using Lightning 3, use the latest 3.4.x version.
> - If you're using Lightning 4, use the latest 4.1.x version.
> - If you're using Lightning 5, use the latest 5.2.x version.
> - If you're using Headless Lightning, use the latest 1.9.x version.

That page gives also other suggestions, for example the following one, for the commands that need to be executed before `drush pm:uninstall lightning`.

> If you're using BLT and `drush status --fields=install-profile` reports that you're directly using the *lightning* or *headless_lightning* profiles, edit *blt/blt.yml* and change the profile key to *minimal*. **Do NOT** do this if you're using a sub-profile of Lightning or Headless Lightning.

As for running `drush pm:uninstall lightning`, these are the suggestions given for that.

> Run `drush pm:uninstall lightning` to use the automated uninstall tool, which will ensure that Lightning can be uninstalled safely by making the necessary code and configuration changes. If you're using a sub-profile of Lightning, you can allow the uninstaller to decouple all sub-profiles automatically by answering the prompt, or see "[Decoupling a sub-profile from Lightning](https://github.com/acquia/lightning/wiki/Uninstalling-Lightning#decoupling-a-sub-profile-from-lightning)" below to do it manually (all sub-profiles, in use or not, must be decoupled from Lightning before you continue). **IMPORTANT**: If you're using Headless Lightning or a sub-profile of it, run `drush pm:uninstall headless_lightning` **BEFORE** running `drush pm:uninstall lightning`.

After running `drush pm:uninstall lightning`, the next step is the following one.

> Export config, then commit all changes and deploy them to your hosting. At a minimum, you should expect to see changes in your project-level *composer.json* and *core.extension* config.

When Lightning hooks into the `drush pm:uninstall` command, it executes the following commands, which essentially switch the profile from Lightning to another one.

- `drush pm:enable profile_switcher`
- `drush switch:profile $profile`

I didn't find any reference to the [Profile Switcher](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile_switcher) module, in the Lightning distribution, despite it is necessary to switch the installation profile, which makes possible to uninstall the distribution. (Otherwise, `drush pm:uninstall lightning` would return the *The Lightning module is required* error.)
If updating the distribution doesn't install it, I would manually install it.

Also, the Lightning hook adds a required option to `drush pm:uninstall`, *profile*, which the installation profile to use instead of the distribution. If after updating the Lightning distribution and following the suggestions given in [Uninstalling Lightning](https://github.com/acquia/lightning/wiki/Uninstalling-Lightning), you get an error about the *profile* option not found or required, try running `drush pm:uninstall lightning --profile='default'` instead of `drush pm:uninstall lightning`, which would pass the *profile* option to the command and the hook added by the distribution.

Comment: Thanks @apaderno I followed your steps and did drush pm:enable profile_switcher but when i try drush switch:profile $profile i get "Not enough arguments (missing: "profile_to_install")." Could you please advise on this

Comment: I am following this https://github.com/acquia/lightning/wiki/Uninstalling-Lightning i ticked all the prerequisites and i upgraded from lightning 4.1.11 to 4.1.2.

Comment: You need to put the profile name, instead of `$profile`, for example `drush switch:profile 'standard'`. I used `$profile` as placeholder.

Comment: Version 4.1.11 is more recent than version 4.1.2. If you had version 4.1.11 installed and you installed version 4.1.2, you down-graded instead of upgrading.

Comment: Truly, the latest 4.1.x version is [release 8.x-4.117](https://www.drupal.org/project/lightning/releases/8.x-4.117), released on August 12, 2021.

Comment: Thanks Can i give anything as the profile name or is it something that should be already existing in my code folder? May i know whats the recent version of lightning 4 . I followed this https://docs.acquia.com/lightning/release-notes/

Comment: It must be a profile that already exists. If you plan to use a contributed installation profile, or distribution, you need to first download it and copy its files in the site directory. *Standard* is one of the installation profiles that comes with Drupal core, so you don't need to download anything, but you can use any installation profile / distribution.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about the versions i have updated lightning to 4.1.17 but now when i try uninstall lightning it says that the profile Standard does not exist. So should i use a contributed installation profile or disturbtion? I had actually enabled the profile switcher and gave the name as Standard and should it be $Standard ?

Comment: The profile name is *Standard* and its machine name is *standard*. Check the *core/profiles/standard/standard.profile* file exists. If it doesn't exist, you need to download the Drupal core files.

Comment: Profile name Standard exists in the core folder as you mentioned. When entering the profile name using Drush I entered it with capital S instead of small does that make any difference as it's a machine name? Now that I am unable to do anything i can not clear caches using Drush or anything for anything I enter it shows The profile Standard does not exist. I even tried to uninstall it but nothing is working

Comment: In settings.global.php  this has already been commented #$settings['install_profile'] = '';  I cam across this suggestion in issues raised in Drupal.org

Comment: Should I update profile_switcher ?  similar to this https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/291522/error-the-module-ldap-does-not-exist-after-composerizing-project

Comment: The latest release of the *Profile Switcher* module has been released on November 24,  2020. You should not have an outdated release. Just to be sure, check the release you installed is 8.x-1.0-alpha5 and update it if it's a previous version. I would also try setting `$settings['install_profile']` to `'standard'`.

Comment: Profile Switcher has the latest version and i uncommented and set it to  ```$settings['install_profile'] = 'standard'``` but its still throwing the same error.

Comment: I followed the instructions that you had suggested. its still throwing the same error as ```Standard does not exist```.